# Send HTTP request from Inno Setup fails

Tags: inno-setup

I've implemented the code below to send HTTP request to a server but for some reason it's not working (no entry on fiddler) can someone help ?
[Edit] I've added Error handling to the code

```pascal
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
...
      
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

; NOTE: Do not use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,My Program}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent


[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'http://publishers-x.databssint.com/', false);
    WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    WinHttpReq.Send('cool');
    // WinHttpReq.ResponseText will hold the server response
    if WinHttpReq.Status <> 200 then
    begin
      MsgBox(WinHttpReq.Status, mbError, MB_OK);
    end
    else
    begin
      MsgBox('SUCCESS', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: From the content type it looks more like you're going to `POST` the request, not `GET`, but it's just my wild guess.

Comment: either way it doesn't work? i'm missing something!

Comment: Yes. As first you are completely missing error handling.

Comment: I've added error handling as you suggested 10x, I get 202, why fiddle doesn't catch it?

Comment: we send JSON to the server

Comment: Without a detailed description of a valid request, or at least a sniffed example transfer we can only guess. The problem might be in wrong parameters, unencoded data, wrong method...

Comment: Error 202 or HTTP status 202? HTTP status codes of 2xx are all successful. 202 also means ["accepted](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.3). It's also entirely possibly that `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest` doesn't honour the system proxy settings. Try Wireshark to see what's being sent over the wire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any 2xx status code is successful. In your case, 202 means ["accepted"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.3). It's deliberately vague, but the request did get through to a server which replied.

As for why it's not showing in Fiddler, Fiddler is at the application level, and acts as a proxy rather than a packet monitor.
The [`WinHttpRequest` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384059(v=vs.85).aspx) implies that it does NOT use the normal system configured proxy, but instead makes use of its own configuration, or values set at run time.

If you want to test with Fiddler, call SetProxy with Fiddler's details:

```
WinHttpReq.SetProxy(2, 'localhost:8888');
```

Alternatively, use WireShark to monitor the network traffic directly.

Comment: I have another thing to ask:
In 'WinHttpReq.Send' i wish to send static text and ExpandConstant I receive from a Function as so : 'function TakeToolParams (Param: String): String;
begin
 if (HPCB.Checked = True) and (DSCB.Checked = True) then
 begin
  Result := **ExpandConstant('true true true');**
 end end;'
I tried this - 'WinHttpReq.Send('cool'+ '{code:TakeToolParams}');'
but it's not working i receive this - cool {code:TakeToolParams}
I actually want to receive this - cool true true true
do you know how to call this function inside 'WinHttpReq.Send'?

Comment: If you have another question, please post or as a new question.