# Send a static text and a `ExpandConstant` in Http request

Tags: inno-setup

In relate to [previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266692/why-send-http-request-doesnt-work/25281738?noredirect=1#comment39413280_25281738) I asked,
In 'WinHttpReq.Send' I wish to send a static text and a `ExpandConstant` which comes from a Function as so : 
`function TakeToolParams (Param: String): String; begin if (HPCB.Checked = True) and (DSCB.Checked = True) then begin Result := ExpandConstant('true true true'); end end;' I tried this - 'WinHttpReq.Send('cool'+ '{code:TakeToolParams}');` but it's not working, I get this on wireshark - **cool {code:TakeToolParams}** I actually want to receive this - **cool true true true**. do you know how to call this function (TakeToolParams) inside 'WinHttpReq.Send'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to expand the constant value. That's where you should use the [`ExpandConstant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) function:

```
WinHttpReq.Send('cool' + ExpandConstant('{code:TakeToolParams}'));
```

But note, that the primary purpose of the [`{code:...}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) constants is for script sections. If you'll be using your `TakeToolParams` function only in [`[Code]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcreating) section, better write it as a standalone function, which you can call directly without constant expanding, e.g.:

```
function TakeToolParams: string;
begin
  Result := 'Some text';
end;
```

In that case you could call it directly:

```
WinHttpReq.Send('cool' + TakeToolParams);
```

Comment: 10X, can you add an example to "as standalone function"

Comment: Just did it (a minute ago :-)

Comment: by the way , how can I get a 'checkbox.State' value?

Comment: Semantically there's no difference between functions that I called standalone and those used for `{code:}` constants. The only difference is in the way you can call them. Standalone functions cannot be used with `{code:}` constant unless they match the `{code:}` constant function prototype (unless they have one string parameter, in your case the `Param`). But except that they are just ordinary functions, so you can do it the same way as you did before.